# 301 Redirect based on referrer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Having an issue with redirection ...

I have my domain forwarded (domain.com > domain-2.com)

My problem is when I browse to domain.com/anything-here it redirects me to domain-2.com/anything-here.

Is there a way in htaccess to redirect all urls from domain.com to just go to the home page of domain-2.com?

Essentially domain.com/* > domain-2.com

`RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ???????? [NC,L]`

Comment: The referrer can’t be trusted (please research if you don’t know why). Can you apply rewriting on your first domain, meaning do you have access to the web server that handles requests for this domain, or how exactly does your “forwarding” work?

Comment: Leaving referrer a side, can't you not modify, your existing forward rule such that forward from domain.com to domain2.com end up in homepage?

Comment: I do have access to the first domain, but as of now I just have forward turned on through godaddy ...